# Can't Programatically Upload csv File with WebClient .Net 4.0

Tags: c#, csv, file-upload, .net-4.0, webclient

I am attempting to upload a csv file but I can't seem to get it to work programatically.  If I use Postman in Chrome to send the file it works and here is what it sends (Fiddler output):

```
------WebKitFormBoundary2YsMyLR3QAPruTy4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Content-Type"; filename="613022.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

// File Content here

------WebKitFormBoundary2YsMyLR3QAPruTy4--
```

However, using this code:

```
   WebClient wc = new WebClient();
   wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pw);
   wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Cookie] = "OBBasicAuth=fromDialog";
   wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
   wc.UploadFile(baseURL + service + apiVersion + resource, "post", file);
```

Results in (Fiddler output):

```
-----------------------8d101dbe85fe96c
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="613022.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

// File Content here

-----------------------8d101dbe85fe96c--
```

Which does not work and the server returns a 503 error.  The only difference I see is in the Content-Disposition name.  How can I set this or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: Does it work if you set the `Content-Disposition` Header manually and use `UploadData` instead of `UploadFile`?

Comment: I did try to set the Content-Disposition manually with 'wc.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Content-Type\"");' however that did not work either.  I did not try UploadData but it appears I have to pass it a byte array and I am not sure how to go about that

Comment: Assuming `file` is a string containing the filename, `File.ReadAllBytes(file)` returns the contents of the file as byte array.

Comment: I changed from UploadFile to UploadData with `byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
wc.UploadData(baseURL + service + apiVersion + resource, "POST", fileBytes);` but that resulted in error 415 Unsupported Media Type

Comment: Maybe try `PUT` instead of `POST` as the request method. Do you have some kind of documentation on what exactly the server expects? Otherwise we're really just guessing here...

Comment: Yes, the documentation says it must be "POST /batch" batch is the csv file and "Content-Type: multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need "upload" instead of "post" in the method parameters - just guessing.

Comment: Thanks but that results in error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Comment: I looked at the description of the 405 error...from there, is it possible that "put" is the appropriate action?

Comment: Thanks but the documentation specifies that POST is the only allowed method

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem with your original approach is that `WebClient.UploadFile` generates the `multipart/form-data` request in a way that is unexpected by the server, hence the 5xx error code.

After looking around for a bit, I think the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785411/since-webclients-uploaddata-doesnt-encode-data-then-what-will-be-the-effect-o) should give you a starting point to tweak the request according to your needs.

Comment: I was able to get UploadFile to work by adding: `wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "any value");` But I am not sure which value to use for the user agent string.  Does it really matter which value is used in this case?

Comment: I don't know. It depends on the server you're sending the request to, since the server decides how it interprets the headers and which fields are required.

Since you got it working with `"any value"`, I guess that the server only checks the value to handle specific known clients differently or maybe for logging purposes.

I would direct this question to the vendor of the web service. It may very well be that this is a bug.

Comment: Thanks, I emailed the vendor to inquire about an appropriate value.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: The vendor confirmed it was a bug.  Thanks again for your help